# How to drop down menu will drop in zero second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down menu of JS in my website [Please click here for website](http://www.fedri.com) but its dropping very slow. Below is the JS code I am having. Please let me know how to make it to drop fast in Zero Second...

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#mega-menu-7').dcMegaMenu({
        rowItems: '3',
        speed: 'fast',
        effect: 'slide'
    });
});
```

Comment: Just use CSS visibility instead of animating. You can position the menu's under the main menu and just make them all invisible. turn the CSS to visible if you hover over, and back to invisible if you hover out. You might need some tweaks for the dropdowns to stay visible offcourse, but there is enough material on the internet about it :)

Comment: did you try `speed: 0,` usually jQuery uses speed fast as a reference of X miliseconds

Comment: yah i tried with speed 0 but not working

Answer (score 1):

Change `speed: 'fast'` to `speed: 0`.  `dcMegaMenu` uses the literal `speed` value for the animation time, so if you set it to 0 it doesn't actually animate and will perform the transition instantly.

Comment: I don't think the options are similar to `.animate()` function.

Comment: @Starx I looked at the [actual code](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/wp-content/themes/dclab/js/jquery.dcmegamenu.1.3.2.js) to see how it is used, and it just plugs the value of `.speed` into `.show` and `.fadeIn`.